# While running composer dump-autoload I'm getting error 255

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

While running composer dump-autoload I'm getting error an error

> Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255

Comment: Can you post the full error from the logs?

Comment: I have the same problem trying to install laravel 5.6 on BlueHost hosting. The post-autoload-dump script is triggered not only on dump-autoload, but also on composer install ,update... It is also known that when I get the error I'm using a local version of composer that I call via php script like so `php ~/bin/composer.phar`, because globally installed version is too old and it throwing me another message saying "You made a reference to a non-existent script @php artisan package:discover".

Comment: I can confirm that there is no error log provided on top of what is posted in the question. Unless, if there is a log file there composer is keeping it's more detailed description. If there is a log file or a verbose more for composer - please advice how to get it.

Comment: Use the [`--no-scripts` flag of Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global-options). It prevents executing any scripts, so this excludes failing ones as it excludes all. Normally it suffices to call `composer dump-autoload` afterwards a second time, and if not, remove the the script from composer.json configuration as it is just broken. Review all dependencies *before* using them, e.g. if they fail or have other kind of flaws.  -- @YevgeniyAfanasyev: `-vvv` you can use (or `-v`, then `-vv` and finally `-vvv`).

Answer (score 0):

There is no Composer issue, it's just executing a command by your request that fails.  This is Laravel specific functionality which is just being invoked by Composer on behalf of Laravel. Composer nor its developers cannot fix anything here or help you.

Answer (score -1):

This error is usually related to a syntax in the config file (config/app.php). Have you updated anything there?

for example, a missing comma after a service provider or something like that in the config/app.php

Answer (score -1):

This is an issue with an upgrade from laravel 6 to laravel 7 and smyfony 5.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#symfony-5-related-upgrades